# How to use winrun4j to start the standalone oc4j application service on Windows 2012 server?

Tags: java, windows-server-2012-r2, oc4j, winrun4j

We are running the Oracle standalone OC4J J2EE web application server on our Windows 2012 R2 server.  The command line to start the oc4j server is as follows:

```
`java -jar %J2EE_HOME%\oc4j.jar`
```

The J2EE_HOME system-wide environment variable has been set correctly, and we are able to start the web server from the command line.

```
System Environment Variables:
`JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\bin`
`J2EE_HOME=E:\OC4J\j2ee\home`
```

Now we need to run the OC4J server as a Windows Service.  To do this, we downloaded the WinRun4J open source application.  Following the winrun4j directions, I've performed the following:

```
1) Created a new folder:  E:\Custom_Apps
2) Copied the WinRun4J64 executable to the new folder
3) Renamed the WinRun4J64 executable to OC4J_WebServer
4) Copied the WinRun4J icon to the new folder and renamed it OC4J_WebServer
5) Created an initialization file in the E:\Custom_Apps folder named OC4J_WebServer.
```

The initialization file contains the following lines:

```
>working.directory=E:\Custom_Apps\working\
>vm.location=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
>service.class=%J2EE_HOME%\oc4j.jar
>service.id=OC4JWebServer
>service.name=WinRun4J_OC4J_Service
>service.description=the OC4J Web Server service launched using winRun4J64.
>classpath.1=%JAVA_HOME%\*.jar
>classpath.2=e:\OC4J\*.jar
>classpath.3=e:\Software\WinRun4J\winrun4j\
>vmarg.1=-Xdebug
>vmarg.2=-Xnoagent
>vmarg.3=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n
```

I executed the following commands at the command line to bind the icon and initializaton files to the executable:

`RCEDIT64.exe /I OC4J_WebServer.exe OC4J_WebServer.ico`
   `RCEDIT64.exe /N OC4J_WebServer.exe OC4J_WebServer.ini`

Finally, I ran the `OC4J_WebServer.exe --WinRun4J64:RegisterService` command to create the Windows service.  I received the following error:

```
>E:\Custom_Apps[info] Module Name: E:\Custom_Apps\OC4J_WebServer.exe
>[info] Module INI:  E:\Custom_Apps\OC4J_WebServer.ini
>[info] Module Dir:  E:\Custom_Apps
>[info] INI Dir: E:\Custom_Apps
>[info] Working directory set to: E:\Custom_Apps\working
>[info] Configured vm.location:  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
>[info] Found VM:  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
>[info] Expanding Classpath:  C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\bin\*.jar
>[info] Expanding Classpath:  E:\Software\WinRun4J\winrun4j\
>[info] Generated Classpath:
>[info] VM Args:
>[info] vmarg.0=-Xdebugvmarg.2=-Xnoagent
>vmarg.3=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,
>server=y,suspend=n
>[info] vmarg.1=-Djava.class.path=
>[info] Registering natives for Native class
> [warn] Could not find Native class
>  [err] Could not find service class
>  [err] Failed to initialize service: 1
    `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: e:\OC4J\j2ee\home\oc4j/jar
    `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: e:\OC4J\j2ee\home\oc4j.jar
    `at java.net.URLClassLooader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    `at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    `at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native method)
    `at java.net.URLClassLoader.findclass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    `at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadclass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    `at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadclass(Launcher.java:308)
    `at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadclass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

I make no claims to being a java developer, and was hoping someone could help me out.  All I want to do is to be able to create a Windows service out of the `java -jar %J2EE_HOME%\oc4j.jar` command.

I'd appreciate some help/insight into how to set this up.

Comment: one recommendation: I used WinRun4J myself in the last years and it certainly has its strong points. But for running something as a service I would suggest [Apache Commons Daemon](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/) or Tanuki (as far as I know the x64 version has to be bought and is not available for free)

Comment: Thanks, Marged.  I appreciate your feedback.  I don't know if we can purchase the Apache software or not, but I'll look at that as an option.

Comment: Apache is available at no cost, only Tanuki comes at a price